# Symfony embedRelation options - setting sub-form field visibility

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

The prototype of embedRelation makes reference to an 'options' array (passed as $formArguments/$formargs).

Is it possible to pass an options array:

```
embedRelation("Model","ModelForm",$options_arr);
```

Where the options_arr contains form validator/widgets/etc to set for the relation?

```
$formargs['something']['publish_date'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText();
```

Or is it possible to limit the form fields displayed for a relation in a way like this?

```
$formargs['something']['use_fields'] = array('publish_date');
```

From sfFormDoctrine.class.php
...

```
* Embed a Doctrine_Collection relationship in to a form
*
*     [php]
*     $userForm = new UserForm($user);
*     $userForm->embedRelation('Groups AS groups');
*
* @param  string $relationName  The name of the relation and an optional alias
* @param  string $formClass     The name of the form class to use
* @param  array  $formArguments Arguments to pass to the constructor (related object will be shifted onto the front)
* @param string  $innerDecorator A HTML decorator for each embedded form
* @param string  $decorator      A HTML decorator for the main embedded form
*
* @throws InvalidArgumentException If the relationship is not a collection
*/
public function embedRelation($relationName, $formClass = null, $formArgs = array(), $innerDecorator = null, $decorator = null)
```

...

The closest I've been able to get to a spec for the $formArgs array() is from sfFormPropel.class.php (I'm using doctrine 1.2):

```
* `title`: The title of the collection form once embedded. Defaults to the relation name.
* `embedded_form_class`: The class name of the forms to embed. Uses the model name by default (a form based on a collection of Book objects embeds BookForm objects).
* `collection_form_class`: Class of the collection form to return. Defaults to sfFormPropelCollection.
* `hide_on_new`: If true, the relation form does not appear for new objects. Defaults to false.
* `add_empty`: Whether to allow the user to add new objects to the collection. Defaults to true.
* `add_delete`: Whether to add a delete widget for each object. Defaults to true.
* `remove_fields`: The list of fields to remove from the embedded object forms
* `item_pattern`: The pattern used to name each embedded form. Defaults to '%index%'.

If `add_empty` is set to `true`, the following additional options are available:

* `empty_label`: The label of the empty form. Defaults to 'new' + the relation name.
* `add_link`: The text of the JavaScript link that displays the empty form. Defaults to `Ann new`
* `max_additions`: The max number of additions accepted on the client side. Defaults to 0 (no limit)

If `add_delete` is set to `true`, the following additional options are available:

* `delete_name`: Name of the delete widget. Defaults to 'delete'.
* `delete_widget`: Optional delete widget object. If left null, uses a `sfWidgetFormDelete` instance, which is a checkbox widget with a Javascript confirmation.
* `alert_text`: The text of the Javascript alert to show.
* `hide_parent`: Whether to hide the deleted form when clicking the checkbox. Defaults to true.
* `parent_level`: The number of times parentNode must be called to reach the parent to hide. As a widget doesn't know if it's merged or embedded, this setting allows the JavaScript code used to hide the parent to find it. Recommended values: 6 for embedded form (default), 7 for merged form.
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you put say `array('toto' => 'pwet')` as form args, you will be able to retrieve 'pwet' in your form using `$this->getOption('toto');` From there everything is possible (setting widgets and validators)

Comment: @user739436, do not edit other people's answers to add your own content. Either add a comment, if it is a comment, or, suggest changes if it is a change to their example code.

Comment: @the Tin Man : huh? Did you wish to post this somewhere else?

Comment: No. There was a pending edit on your answer from user739436 that should have been a comment.

Comment: @the Tin Man : oh I wondered why there was no history for my post, now I know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go another way:

```
$o = $this->isNew() ? new Model() : $this->getObject()->getModel();
$model_form = new ModelForm($o);

//now configure widgets and validators
$model_form->setWidget('publish_date', new sfWidgetFormInputText());
$model_form->useFields(array('publish_date'));

$this->embedForm('Model', $model_form);
```